# Truncate table in Oracle

Tags: oracle, truncate

I need to truncate a table that has around 40 million records in it. i guess it is ok to REUSE STORAGE for the table since new data will be inserted after the truncate.
I need to know

1. approximately how much time the command 
   `TRUNCATE TABLE <tablename> REUSE STORAGE;` would take.
2. Can this be done offline, so that the operations/ commands on the DB
   don't get affected?

Comment: What do you mean by "offline"? The RDBMS must be up and running for you to truncate tables.

Comment: @ammoQ he probably means "online" - without stopping current operations )

Comment: that's right... i mean, truncating the table as a background operation without affecting other DB operations/ commands on other tables to much.

Answer (score 4):

Based on "so that the operations/ commands don't get affected", it sounds like you'd like to replace the contents of a table with "good" values, without anyone seeing an empty table.  If users/processes need to be able to continue making changes to the table while you switch out the contents, you'll need to research DBMS_REDEFINITION.  If this is a read-only table (in other words, you can do this operation while nobody is inserting/updating/deleting its contents), there's a nice DIY approach that takes advantage of partition exchanging:

1) Create a table  which has identical partitioning and indexing as original, and has the desired "good" rows.
2)
IF YOUR TABLE IS PARTITIONED:

```
CREATE TABLE <tablename>_TMP AS SELECT * FROM <tablename> WHERE 1=0;

-- Add any local indexes on <tablename> as standard indexes on <tablename_tmp>

BEGIN 
    FOR R IN (SELECT * FROM USER_TAB_PARTITIONS WHERE TABLE_NAME = <tablename>)
    LOOP
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 
            'INSERT INTO <tablename>_TMP' 
            ||' SELECT * FROM <good_data_tablename> PARTITION ('||R.PARTITION_NAME||')';
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
            'ALTER TABLE <tablename>_TMP' 
            ||' EXCHANGE PARTITION WITH TABLE <tablename> PARTITION ' || R.PARTITION_NAME 
            ||' INCLUDING INDEXES WITHOUT VALIDATION UPDATE GLOBAL INDEXES';
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 
            'TRUNCATE TABLE <tablename>_TMP';
    END LOOP    
END;
/

DROP TABLE <tablename>_TMP ;
```

IF YOUR TABLE IS NOT PARTITIONED:

```
CREATE TABLE <tablename>_TMP 
PARTITION BY RANGE (<non-null-column>)
(PARTITION ALL_DATA values less than (maxvalue))
AS SELECT * FROM <good_data_tablename>;

-- Add any <tablename> indexes as local indexes on <tablename>_TMP 

ALTER TABLE <tablename> EXCHANGE PARTITION WITH TABLE <tablename>_TMP INCLUDING INDEXES WITHOUT VALIDATION;

DROP TABLE <tablename>_TMP ;
```

Comment: thanks Kevin. i want to keep this as a last option since we have few indexes, sequences, constraints, etc that are dependent on this table and don't want to get into recreating all of that... i am looking at the options "truncate table <tname> drop storage" and "truncate table <tname> reuse storage". not sure which will complete faster. aproximately, how much time would a truncate table <tname> drop storage take for a table with 40 Million records?

Comment: This will have same effect on dependencies as TRUNCATE+REPOPULATE. Read the code - the only DROP TABLE or CREATE INDEX operations are against the "helper" TMP tables.  This is just a way to TRUNCATE+REPOPULATE without users seeing an empty table.  If you're ok with users seeing an empty table after you TRUNCATE and while you repopulate, then yeah, TRUNCATE+REPOPULATE.  TRUNCATE is nearly instantaneous - usually less than 5 seconds (regardless of STORAGE option) even with lots of partitions/sub-partitions.  You'll need to disable foreign-key dependencies for TRUNCATE *or* PARTITION EXCHANGE.